# Best way to clone existing iOS app with multiple target and different themes for each target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

currently, i am working on an iOS app which is likely to be cloned with multiple targets, and each target will have a different theme.Now I have used the storyboards to create UI and assigning their respective font, color, and other UI Stuff.

please suggest me the fastest way to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

Connect IBOutlets to every view that you want to modify. Create multiple targets and implement in every View method like that:

```
func updateUI() {
  #if TargetA
    viewA.backgroundColor = .red
  #endif
  #if TargetB
    viewA.backgroundColor = .green
  #endif
  #if TargetC
    viewA.backgroundColor = .blue
  #endif
}
```